Using residue theorem to calculate the integral, am I wrong?
$$
\mbox{I encountered an integral}\quad
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{cos(x-ai)}{sin(x-ai)}dx
$$
It is not a difficult problem, but my result is different from the answer. I need help to check where I am wrong.
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{cos(x-ai)}{sin(x-ai)}dx=\int_{C_1} \frac{z^2 e^a+e^{-a}}{z(z^2 e^a-e^{-a})}dz
$$
Here I only use the Euler's identity and let $z=e^{ix}$.

Then notice
$\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{z^2 e^a+e^{-a}}
{z(z^2 e^a-e^{-a})}$
has only a pole (at $0$) with order $1$ within the unit disk, so by residue theorem, the integral is
$2\pi{\rm i}(-1)$, where $-1$ is the residue at $0$. It
seems the result should be $2\pi{\rm i}$, I do not know where I am wrong.
Maybe some details needed for checking.
\begin{align}
\int_{C_1} \frac{z^2 e^a+e^{-a}}{z(z^2 e^a-e^{-a})}dz & = \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \frac{e^{2ix+a}+e^{-a}}{e^{ix}(e^{2ix+a}-e^{-a})} ie^{ix}dz
\\[3mm] & =
i\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \frac{e^{ix+a}+e^{-ix-a}}{e^{ix+a}-e^{-ix-a}}dx =
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{cos(x-ai)}{sin(x-ai)}dx
\end{align}


How about just doing the integral of cotangent?

$f(z)$ also has poles at $z = \pm e^{-a}$, which are within the unit disk if $\text{Re}(a) > 0$.

$\sin(x-a\mathrm{i}) = 0 \iff x = 2\pi k + a\mathrm{i}, k \in \Bbb{Z}$.  For the pole to be at $x = 0$, you must have that $a$ is an integer multiple of $2\pi\mathrm{i}$.  You don't state that constraint on $a$.  (In fact, you don't even say if $a$ is real, rational, an integer, ..., positive, nonzero, ...)
